# Remove unpushed commit without removing local changes

Tags: git, github

I was writing some computational codes locally and sync them with Github. I recently wrote some new code and tested it with some large size data file inside the folder. I did not pay attention to the size of the file, until I add and commit the whole folder and try to push it. However errors indicating file size is too big to push.

I am quite new to git, so I figured just to remove the generated data file from the folder, but only realized the commit has already log the oversized data file. I look around and found options like git revert command. But it seems like once I git revert, all the code I've updated with go back to the previous commit. I just wanna recommit without the oversized data file included so that I can make a successful push. Is there any one can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:

`$ git reset HEAD^`

it will remove your latest commit, but keep the changes in your working tree so you can create a new commit but modify what is included.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Does HEAD^ means the previous git status?

Comment: `HEAD` is just a reference to the commit you have checked out, in your case it’s your unpushed commit. `HEAD^` is the parent commit, this is the commit you had before your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply tell git to remove the file from index and then amend your last commit.

```
git rm --cached path/to/your/file
git commit --amend
```

With `git rm --cached` you just remove the file from index but keep it on your file system and with  `git commit --amend` you modify your last commit including these changes. Every change you have staged will be incorporated. You get even the chance to modify the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git reset path/to/file
git commit
```

Explanation

`git reset -soft HEAD~1` will reset your last commit (`HEAD~1` is reference to the last commit) but keep the changes staged, from there we can unstage the file by `git reset path/to/file`.